# Memory leaks in CoreMotion

Tags: iphone, ios, memory, memory-leaks, cmmotionmanager

Following is my code in vievDidLoad

```
CMMotionManager *motionmanager = [[[CMMotionManager alloc]init]autorelease];

NSString string1 = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"%s", ([motionmanager.isGyroAvailable} ? @"Available" : @"Not Available"));
```

In Instruments i get memory leaks referring CMMotionManagerInternal in XCode 4.5
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: check in build analyser and fix the object level leaks

Comment: I suppose you mean Analyze from the menu. No problem found there

Answer (score 1):

The `CMMotionManager`line seems fine, however you should consider keeping the reference (make it instance variable and not autorelease it) and release the `CMMotionManager` manually when you stop updating data from it.

The other line bothers me more. You have

```
NSString string1 = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"%s", ([motionmanager.isGyroAvailable} ? @"Available" : @"Not Available"));
```

While you should have:

```
NSString *string1 = [NSString stringwithFormat:@"%@", ([motionmanager.isGyroAvailable} ? @"Available" : @"Not Available"));
```

so `string1` should be a pointer and format is `@"%@"` not `@"%s"`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't pasted my code correctly. Indeed I have it as @"%@" and not @"%s". So I think that's not the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a bug in the simulator. It's working properly on the device.